# Did Blender 3.0 change the selection process?

Tags: selection-tools, select

Previously I could easily select the object behind by just clicking twice (or more if there are more layers), but now it doesn't seem to work. Moreover, I can't select smaller objects at all (only via layers panel on the right)

Answer (score 1):

No, 3.0 didn't change that aspect of the selection process.  However, there is an option in preferences *OpenGL Depth Picking* that influences it.  To check whether you have accidentally disabled it, *Edit→Preferences*; select *Viewport* and see if it is checked:

[image: Viewport Preferences with OpenGL Depth Picking highlighted.]

If the option is not set, then selecting an object behind another one fails.

Comment: thank you. It turned out to be a bug, I think. No such problem in 3.1.0